# How to call Struts2 Action method in ajax?

Tags: ajax, struts2

How to call Struts2 Action method in ajax.Still now i worked to call servlet.is there any possibilities?if so please do share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a Servlet you can also call an Struts2 Action.

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ajax.html

Struts2 supports also different AJAX Frameworks like jQuery/Dojo/YUI 
with different plugins.

Answer (score 9):

Update the **`struts.xml`** as

```
<package name="prjajax" namespace="/" extends="json-default">

<result-types>
    <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" />
</result-types>
<action name="AJAXAction" class="com.demo.sd.prj.ui.actions.AJAXAction" method="myMethod">
    <result name="success" type="json" />
</action>
```

**`jQuery code:`**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "AJAXAction",
    type: "POST",
    data: {data: $('#txtbox').val()},
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Error ' + textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    },
    success: function(data){         
        alert('SUCCESS');

       }
});
```

Comment: and how can we send params?

Comment: ok i just figured our that u need to replace the second data word by the name of the variable in your action class, and the txtbox word by the name/id (i dont know which exactly, but probably the id) of the element in your jsp page. And to send multiple params, then i guess you can do something like data: {actionVariable1: $('#txtbox1').val(),actionVariable2: $('#txtbox2').val()}