# Load div using Struts 2 jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, struts, struts-html

I am creating a struts based application and i want to load a div based on content in a sj:textfield. I am using struts jquery plugin. 
The div has to be loaded by passing the textfield contents to a struts action.

Can anyone tell me how to do so since I could not find any instance of this anywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Struts2 Action method in ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239960/how-to-call-struts2-action-method-in-ajax)

Comment: @jigar-joshi nope, there what they are asking is how to call Struts2 Action method in ajax, that's different. Here, i want to know if it is possible to load a div without a submit button using ajax by passing form parameters to struts action as the user types.

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure, if i got u right. but i will give a try. check out the code below

```
<s:form action="action">
  <sj:textfield name="name" value="value" label="label/>
  <sj:submit targets="myResultDiv"/>
</s:form>

<div id="myResultDiv"></div>
```

after you submit the form, the result should be appeared in the div with id "myResultDiv", check out the struts2 jquery plugin page [strut2-jquery-plugin-showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)

## EDIT 1

```
<s:form id="myForm" action="action">
  <sj:textfield name="name" value="value" label="label" onChangeTopics="changeTopic"/>
</s:form>

<div id="myResultDiv"></div>
<script>
$.subscribe('changeTopic', function(event, data) {
var ui = event.originalEvent.ui;
if(ui.item) {
    $('#myResultDiv').html('<p>'+message+'</p>');
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: actually, the form should not have a submit button. What i wanted is that the form should be submitted for each character, like autocomplete but the results should be loaded in the div tag.

Comment: is it possible using the plugin or should i include jquery javascript?

Comment: @nkvp you do not have to include jquery, once you include <sj:head/>, jquery is automatically included. if u do not like to have a submit in the form, c EDIT 1

Comment: ok... sorry i didn't see it... but how does the form get submitted in the example? ill check and see.. what is "message" in the code?